# What makes a program load so fast?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, ram, load, lightweight

I have this question that I need an answer to.

What makes programs like [st](https://st.suckless.org/), [zathura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zathura_(document_viewer)), [sxiv](https://github.com/muennich/sxiv), and [feh](https://feh.finalrewind.org/) load instantly and what makes programs like [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/) load so slowly in low-spec computers?

For example, I have a low-spec laptop running Linux Mint. And when I execute **st**, it instantly opens an **st** instance, but when I execute **Google Chrome**, it takes a long time to open a **Google Chrome** instance.
What makes st load faster than Google Chrome and what makes Google Chrome load slower than st.

Thank you! :)

Comment: This question is basically asking "why does a Ferrari accelerate faster than a tank"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

feh does not do much comparing to Google Chrome. Just compare the files sizes
and the number of dependencies:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 187751032 May 13 05:50 /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
$ ls -l $(which feh)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 207280 Feb  2 21:03 /usr/bin/feh
$ ldd /usr/lib/chromium/chromium | wc -l
178
$ ldd $(which feh) | wc -l
49
```

Besides, Google Chrome includes its own modified versions of many open source libraries that it depends on. It is huge and it takes much longer to load.

Answer (score 1):

On modern Unix (including Linux) much of the program is shared libraries, which stay in memory. When starting a program, the dynamic linker (`libc.so`) runs and resolves libraries, etc. That takes time, and much of the program has to be loaded into memory too. Add to that any initialization the program does (e.g. reopening web pages shown on tabs,...). Besides, if you run the same program twice in a row, a part of the memory image (at least shared libraries) will still be  around, speeding up the process. If the program only uses popular shared libraries, they will probably will be around anyway.